# Using Microsoft's Metro Style Api for non Windows 8 Webpages

Tags: jquery, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winjs, tiles

Has anyone used Microsoft's Metro Style Api to develop webpages that are supported in all major browsers, NOT Windows 8?
I'm kind of new to this (jquery, Metro styles), and need to make a webpage that pretty much acts like a Metro style App, with live tiles and all.

Comment: Live tiles are part of the start screen, not the app.  What specifically are you asking about?

Comment: Basically I need to do a WebApplication that looks like a Metro App. It consists of some tiles that are constantly flipping and some other features. And I was asked to use MS's Metro Api, although I'm not sure that it'll really solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

(Old answer not valid anymore) The APIs are part of Windows 8. Can't use them in non-Windows 8 environments.

WinJS is now open source and can be used anywhere. Get it at http://try.buildwinjs.com.

Comment: Yes, that's what I feared. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the update, Filip--I appreciate you taking the time to keep things current!

Comment: Sure thing. I was just passing by, clearing some microsoft-metro tags and noticed this.

Answer (score 0):

The Metro APIs allow you to interact with the system and do other things that are impossible to do in a webapp.

You want to use CSS & Javascript to make a web page that uses the same design techniques as Metro-style apps.  (lots of colored rectangles, careful use of typography)

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be that way. I'll probably use some plug-in to help out, but there really doens't seem to be an API that magically does Metro WebApps